# Why are zombie pigmen attacking for no reason?

Tags: mods, minecraft-java-edition

It's a well known fact, that zombie pigmen are passive mobs. I was always relying on that, and recently one of them attacked me for no reason. As soon as I showed up in his line of sight, he started running towards me and hitting with his sword. I was deeply shocked. What changed? What could possibly happen?

Background info:

- Minecraft 1.0.0 SMP
- Modded, with the latest [TechnicMP Unofficial Update](https://yogscast.com/showthread.php?38573-TechnicMP-Unofficial-Update-1.12.0-%28still-for-MC-beta-1.8.1%29)
- In the Nether
- I was in process of digging out [Nether Ores](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/554413-100smp-pcs-mods-minefactory-reloaded-power-converters-and-more-updated-dec-19th/#no)

List of significant mods:

- IndustrialCraft2 1.43
- BuildCraft 2.2.9
- RedPower 2.0pre4
- Forestry 1.2.4.4
- Minefactory Reloaded 1.4
- Nether Ores 1.1.0
- Wireless Redstone 1.5
- Railcraft 2.1.1

Now some of them instantly attack me, some prefer not to. Is this part of one of the mods? Or I've missed something in the 1.0.0 change-log?

Comment: I run a CraftBukkit server, have none of those mods, but the I have encountered the same problem. All of them attacked on sight.

Comment: They're only passive if you didn't attack anything else in their range, I think...

Comment: I've rushed with asking a question, should have checked the Nether Ores forum post first. A little sentence in the credits explains everything: "Thanks to IceWolf (whose mcf username I forgot) for the pigmen angering idea!". The digging was triggering pigmen. I'll post this as an answer, when I'll be able to (have to wait for 8 hours, since I don't have 100+ rep).

Comment: @MyFaJoArCo You can self answer btw! There's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @badp I know, but when I tried to do so - I got a warning, saying that I don't have enough reputation to self answer sooner than 8 hours after asking the question. So, Leo has used the possibility :)

Comment: @MyFaJoArCo Oh... I didn't know self answering was now tied to reputation. That's kinda weird

Comment: @badp Yes, I was surprised too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you dig up ores in the line of range they will attack you. This behavior is added by the Nether Ores mod.

Comment: Thanks, but I've already answered that four hours ago in comments :) If you'll edit your answer to the proper quality (at least capitalize "if") - I'll mark it as an accepted.